# How to flat a Series list of dictionaries in Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I convert a Series list of dictionaries into a DataFrame? Given:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "detail": [
            {
                "name" : "name1",
                "type" : "type1",
            },
                        {
                "name" : "name2",
                "type" : "type2",
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "detail": [
            {
                "name" : "name3",
                "type" : "type3",
            },
                        {
                "name" : "name4",
                "type" : "type4",
            },
        ]
    },
]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to turn the above into a DataFrame:

```
       id      detail_name      detail_type
0       1    name1 | name2    type1 | name2
1       2    name3 | name4    type3 | name4
```

Obs: The `|` is just a character to separate the concat records, it can be any character.

I tried using `pd.json_normalize` and joining after, but json_normalize will generate (4, 2) shaped dataframe.

```
details = pd.json_normalize(data,record_path=['detail'],record_prefix='detail_',)
df = df.join([details])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data).explode("detail")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("detail").apply(pd.Series).add_prefix("detail_")], axis=1)
df = df.groupby("id").agg(" | ".join).reset_index()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   id    detail_name    detail_type
0   1  name1 | name2  type1 | type2
1   2  name3 | name4  type3 | type4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of meta as part of your json_normalize to persist the 'id' and use it as your key for grouping the resulting records.

```
>>> df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path="detail", record_prefix="detail.", meta="id").groupby("id").agg("|".join).reset_index()
>>> df
   id  detail.name  detail.type
0   1  name1|name2  type1|type2
1   2  name3|name4  type3|type4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (*that should be fast*) :

```
cols = dict.fromkeys([k for nd in data[0].get("detail") for k in nd.keys()])
# or cols = ['name', 'type']

records = [
    {
        "id": d["id"],
        **{
            f"detail_{c}": " | ".join(nd[c] for nd in d["detail"])
            for c in cols
        }
    } for d in data
]

df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

---

```
# 399 µs ± 13.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   id    detail_name    detail_type
0   1  name1 | name2  type1 | type2
1   2  name3 | name4  type3 | type4
```